# LLVM: usage of getUniqueExitBlock()

Tags: loops, llvm

How do I use the function `Loops::getUniqueExitBlock()` from `LoopInfo.h` in my llvm pass?
I do not understand, how do I call this function for a particular loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `getUniqueExitBlock()` states:

> getUniqueExitBlock - If getUniqueExitBlocks would return exactly one
>   block, return that block.
>
> Otherwise return null.

This tells us that `getUniqueExitBlock()` is a convenience method to check to see if the loop has only one exit block. If it does, return it - otherwise return null.

Assuming you have a way to get `Loop` objects, you can use this function by doing something like

```
auto loop = get_loop() // you have to write this part
auto exit = loop->getUniqueExitBlock() // calls the function
if(exit != nullptr) {
    // exit points to the block that the loop jumps to when it exits
} else {
    // exit is null - this means that the loop either has more than one exit block or no exit blocks. deal with this case
}
```

Documentation for all of the LLVM API can be found [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/). Sometimes the API isn't documented so well, as is the case with the new `Attribute` API. In this case, it's useful to look through the code itself for examples of the function being used within the LLVM codebase itself. For example, the documentation for `getUniqueExitBlock()` tells us that it's referenced internally by [`llvm::UnrollRuntimeLoopProlog()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/LoopUnrollRuntime_8cpp_source.html#l00280). This example can help you understand how to properly use `getUniqueExitBlock()`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask, how to start about the function `get_loop()`.

Comment: Well there are a few ways to do it. One way would be to write a loop pass (http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-looppass-class)

Comment: Actually, I already am doing some instrumentation inside a module pass. Can I use integrate it inside the module pass itself ?

Comment: You can get analysis info within a module pass by overriding the `getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage&)` function. More info at http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#specifying-interactions-between-passes. You could use this function to require the LoopInfo analysis pass and then iterate over the list of loops in LoopInfo.

Comment: As Matt said there are a few ways of doing it, you can also use 'loop->getExitBlocks(ExitBBs)' and then check  'ExitBBs->size()' .  if it helps you to have loops with one exit block, then  add AU.addRequiredID(LoopSimplifyID) to getAnalysisUsage() of your pass, since LoopSimplify might reduce number of the ExitBlocks.